# Get-WinEvent Script

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

I have a powershell script which is working as expected. I need some help with formatting the output.

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
Get-ChildItem –Path "D:\Log\" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt $Date)} | Remove-Item
$filter = @{
LogName='Application'
StartTime=$Date
}
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter | Select-Object TimeCreated,Message | 
Where-Object { $_.Message -like '*renamed*' -and $_.Message -notlike "*csv*" } |
Out-File -FilePath D:\Log\DailyReport_$(get-date -Format yyyyddmm_hhmmtt).txt
```

The output is

```
TimeCreated          Message                                                                                                                             
-----------          -------                                                                                                                             
4/16/2020 4:03:30 AM 04712: renamed
```

I need the output to be

```
Date Time,File Name

4/16/2020 4:03:30 AM, 04712: renamed
```

The column header needs to be renamed with a comma. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Arnab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename the properties with `Select-Object` and convert to comma-separated values with `ConvertTo-Csv` or `Export-Csv`:

```bsh
# ...
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter |
  Select-Object TimeCreated,Message |
  Where-Object { $_.Message -like '*renamed*' -and $_.Message -notlike "*csv*" } |
  Select-Object @{Name='Date Time';Expression='TimeCreated'},@{Name='File Name';Expression='Message'} |
  Export-Csv D:\Log\DailyReport_$(get-date -Format yyyyddmm_hhmmtt).txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias, is there a way I can removed the quotation marks due to the Export-csv. Everything else looks perfect.